# Combine Filter to include and Exclude

Tags: rust

I have some data which I want to filter. I have a collection of things to include and a second one of things to exclude.

Currently I'm looping my data and filter once for the including and a second time for the excluding.

Example coding:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Dataset {
    pub data: Vec<String>
}

fn main() {
    //setup test data
    let mut ds1_data : Vec<String> = Vec::with_capacity(2);
    ds1_data.push("a".to_string());
    ds1_data.push("b".to_string());
    let ds1 = Dataset{data: ds1_data};

    let mut ds2_data : Vec<String> = Vec::with_capacity(2);
    ds2_data.push("a".to_string());
    ds2_data.push("c".to_string());
    let ds2 = Dataset{data: ds2_data};

    let mut datasets : Vec<Dataset> = Vec::with_capacity(2);
    datasets.push(ds1);
    datasets.push(ds2);

    let mut include : Vec<String> = Vec::with_capacity(2);
    include.push("a".to_string());

    let mut exclude : Vec<String> = Vec::with_capacity(1);
    exclude.push("b".to_string());

    //filter datasets
    for ds in datasets {
        if ds.data.iter().find(|d| include.contains(d)).is_none() {
            //skip not included
            continue;
        }        
        if ds.data.iter().find(|d| exclude.contains(d)).is_some() {
            //skip excluded
            continue;
        }

        println!("{:?}", ds);
    }
}
```

Also available in the rust playground:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=29c13f2b7ab3a50fbcd12b88b59f4b74

Is there way to combine the filter statements so I don't need to iterate ds.data two times?

---

To clarify:
The above coding is working as expected. I get datasets containing at least one element of include but no element of exclude

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to filter. Do you want to keep only datasets that have all elements of `include` and no elements of `exclude`?

Comment: I want to get datasets containing at least one element of include, but no element of exclude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The `vec!` macro

Before we have a look at including and excluding, we should note that

```
let mut myvec: Vec<T> = Vec::with_capacity(2);
myvec.push(a);
myvec.push(b);
myvec.push(c);
```

can be written with the [`vec!` macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.vec.html) as

```
let myvec: Vec<T> = vec![a,b,c];
```

This has the nice side-effect that `myvec` doesn't need to be `mut` anymore. If we apply this too all your code, we end up with

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Dataset {
    pub data: Vec<String>,
}
fn main() {
    //setup test data
    let ds1_data = vec!["a".to_string(), "b".to_string()];
    let ds1 = Dataset { data: ds1_data };

    let ds2_data = vec!["a".to_string(), "c".to_string()];
    let ds2 = Dataset { data: ds2_data };

    let datasets = vec![ds1, ds2];

    let include = vec!["a".to_string()];
    let exclude = vec!["b".to_string()];

    //filter datasets
    for ds in datasets {
        if ds.data.iter().find(|d| include.contains(d)).is_none() {
            continue;
        }
        if ds.data.iter().find(|d| exclude.contains(d)).is_some() {
            continue;
        }

        println!("{:?}", ds);
    }
}
```

That's a lot less noise, perfect to concentrate on the original problem.

## Including and excluding

First of all, instead of `find(…).is_some()`, we can use [`any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.any), and instead of `find(…).is_none()` too. We could use that to simplify the expressions, but we would still traverse the set twice.

```
for ds in datasets {
    if !ds.data.iter().any(|d| include.contains(d)) {
        //skip not included
        continue;
    }        
    if ds.data.iter().any(|d| exclude.contains(d)) {
        //skip excluded
        continue;
    }

    println!("{:?}", ds);
}
```

Instead, let's think about the elements we have to look at. The answer is all, as `exclude` might match the last element in our dataset, even if `include` matched the first.

As we have to look at all elements either way, we might as well traverse them by hand:

```
    for ds in datasets {
        let mut included = false;
        let mut excluded = false;
        for d in &ds.data {
            if included == false && include.contains(d) {
                included = true;
            }
            if exclude.contains(d) {
                excluded = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if included == false || excluded == true {
            continue;
        }

        println!("{:?}", ds);
    }
```

Now that we have this as a blueprint, we can check the [iterators](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) for a fitting method. We need to

- check that at least one `include` matches
- check that no `exclude` matches
- stop as soon as soon as *any* `exclude` matches.

Unfortunately it's not possible to quick exit from a closure, so the last requirement cannot be done with `fold` or similar. However, we can use `inspect` and `all` to get something like our previous loop:

```
    for ds in datasets {
        let mut included = false;

        if !ds
            .data
            .iter()
            .inspect(|d| {
                if included == false || include.contains(d) {
                    included = true
                }
            })
            .all(|d| !exclude.contains(d))
            || !included
        {
            continue;
        }
        println!("{:?}", ds);
    }
```

But that's a lot less readable than our previous loop, which did the same. We could increase readablity if we introduced a function, but that's left as an exercise. In the end, we would need a `fold`-like function that supports an early exit, but such a function does not exist.